# Method of Moments for Gamma distribution- histogram and superimposing the PDF

Tags: r, pdf, histogram, curve, gamma-distribution

I have this question. 'Model the data in nfsold (nfsold is just a vector containing 150 numbers)as a set of 150independent observations from a Gamma(lambda; k) distribution. Use the Method of Moments, to obtain estimates of k and lambda. Draw a histogram of the data and superimpose the PDF of your fitted gamma distribution as a preliminary check that this distribution matches the observed data.'

This is the code I have written.

```
#The first moment of each Xi, i = 1,...,n, is E(Xi) = k/lamda.
#The second moment of each Xi is E(Xi^2) = k(k+1)/(lamda)^2
#Since we have to find 2 two things, k and lamda we require 2 moments to do this.

x_bar = mean = sum(nfsold)/150 #This is the first moment

mean

second_moment = sum(nfsold^2)/150
second_moment
#(1/n)(sum xi) = k/lamda
#(1/n)(sum x^2i) = k(k+1)/(lamda)^2
#By solving these because of the methods of moments we get lambda and k.

lamda_hat = (x_bar)/((second_moment)-(x_bar)^2)

lamda_hat

k_hat = (x_bar)^2/ ((second_moment)-(x_bar)^2)

k_hat

independent_observations = dgamma(x,k_hat, rate = lamda_hat)

hist( independent_observations, breaks = 15, prob = TRUE, main="Histogram for the Gamma Distribution of the data in nfsold", xlab="Independent Observations", ylab="P.D.F")

curve(dgamma(x,k_hat, rate =lamda_hat), add=TRUE, col="green")
```

My problem is that my superimposed curve does not follow my histogram, so I feel like there is something wrong with my code, please would I be able to have some help with correcting it?

Thanks!